# Changing the color of individual elements in a JSON Array

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, json

I have HTML and vanilla JS code for creating a type writer effect. I would like to have each element of the array appear on screen in a different color. Here's my example code:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('txt-rotate');
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var toRotate = elements[i].getAttribute('data-rotate');
    var period = elements[i].getAttribute('data-period');
    if (toRotate) {
      new TxtRotate(elements[i], JSON.parse(toRotate), period);
    }
  }
};
```

```html
<h1 class="big-title">ANIMALS
  <span class="txt-rotate" data-period="2000" data-rotate='[ "DOG", "CAT", "BEAR"]'>
          </span>
</h1>
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is `TxtRotate`?

Comment: This seems like something that needs to be in the `TxtRotate` class. It should change the color whenever it rotates the array.

Comment: TxtRotate is my function which changes the text by deleting and retyping the elements in the data-rotate array

Comment: Since it's changing the text, it also needs to change the color when it does that. It can assign to `div.style.color`

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be either to use style.color like @Barmar mentioned, but this is my personal favorite, i think it's specific to ajax though

```
$.("#txt-rotate").css("color", "#ff0000");
```